# How to make a check correction of date and split not a standart string AWK

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

I have got an input file with following syntax:

```
"ID","Company Name","AccountManager","Product","Support Type","Country"
```

Example:

```
"1","Company one","Surname Name / Phone/ Cell Phone ","Product► (d2XXXXXX) ► Version","29.10.2012 ► Type of support","Russia"

"2","Company two","Surname Name / Phone/ Cell Phone ","Product► (d2XXXXXX) ► Version\nProduct► (d2XXXXXX) ► Version\nProduct► (d2XXXXXX) ► Version","31.10.2012 ► Type of support\n28.10.2012 ► Type of support\nn/a ► Type of support","Foreign"

"3","Company three","Surname Name / Phone/ Cell Phone ","Product► (d2XXXXXX) ► Version\nProduct► (d2XXXXXX) ► Version\nProduct► (d2XXXXXX) ► Version\nProduct► (d2XXXXXX) ► Version\nProduct► (d2XXXXXX) ► Version\nProduct► (d2XXXXXX) ► Version,"31.12.2012 ► Type of support\nType of support\nn\\a ► Type of support\n31.03.2013 ► Type of support\n25.10.2012 ► Type of support\nn\\a ► Type of support","Russia"

"4","Company fourth","Surname Name / Phone/ Cell Phone ","1) Product► (d2XXXXXX) ► Version\n2) Product► (d2XXXXXX) ► Version\n3) Product► (d2XXXXXX) ► Version\n4) Product► (d2XXXXXX) ► Version\n5) Product► (d2XXXXXX) ► Version\n6) Product► (d2XXXXXX) ► Version,"1) 31.12.2012 ► Type of support\n2) Type of support\n3) n\\a ► Type of support\n4) 31.03.2013 ► Type of support\n5) 25.10.2012 ► Type of support\n6) n\\a ► Type of support","Foreign"

"5","Company five","Surname Name / Phone/ Cell Phone ","Product► (d2XXXXXX) ► Version","33.10.2012 ► Type of support","Russia"
```

The first company has only one product, the second company has 3 products - they are separated with `\n` (Product and Support Type), the third company has 6 products, the fouth company has 6 products, but not in a standart string (1), 2) and etc.), the fifth company has 1 product, but there is an error in date (33).

In the output this string must be separate and repeat values of the columns:

`"ID","Company Name","AccountManager","Country"`, but `"AccountManager"` should have only Surname and Name, and column Support Type should be compared with today date - if date in support type different with today date in values from 27 to 32 days this columns must be in output file. If we have got `n/a` in the Support Type it should be missed.

The output should look like:
In file Russia.csv:

```
"1","Company one","Surname Name","Product► (d2XXXXXX) ► Version","29.10.2012","Russia"
"3","Company three","Surname Name","Product► (d2XXXXXX) ► Version","25.10.2012","Russia"
```

In file Foreign.csv:

```
"2","Company two","Surname Name","Product► (d2XXXXXX) ► Version","28.10.2012","Foreign"
"2","Company two","Surname Name","Product► (d2XXXXXX) ► Version","31.10.2012","Foreign"
"4","Company fourth","Surname Name","Product► (d2XXXXXX) ► Version","25.10.2012","Foreign"
```

In Error.csv:

```
 Error in date! "5","Company five","Surname Name / Phone/ Cell Phone ","Product► (d2XXXXXX) ► Version","33.10.2012 ► Type of support","Russia"
```

I have got a script that compare with dates (27 to 32) but not with checking correct date, splitting strings with counting and separate files output:

```
#/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS=",";
    "date +\"%s\"" | getline curr_timestamp;
}

{
    split($3, account, "/");
    gsub(/ $/, "", account[1]);
    split($4, products, "\\\\n");
    split($5, supports, "\\\\n");
    for (i in products) {
        gsub("\"", "", products[i]);
        gsub("\"", "", supports[i]);
        split(supports[i], timesupport, " ");
        # ignore not available and support without date
        if (supports[i] !~ /n\\\\a*/ && supports[i] !~ /n\/a*/ && $2 !~ /\NULL/ && timesupport[1] ~ /[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/) {
            # formatting date
            split(timesupport[1], date, "\.");
            mydate = "date -d \""date[3]"/"date[2]"/"date[1]"\" \"+%s\"";
            # date to timestamp (using bash)
            mydate | getline timestamp;
            # timestamp is >= 27 days and <= 32 days
            if ((timestamp-curr_timestamp) >= 2332800 && (timestamp-curr_timestamp) <= 2764800)
                print $1","$2","account[1]"\",\""products[i]"\",\""supports[i]"\","$6;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is the source of your data from Windows? where RS="\r\n"? Did you know that with awk (and unix in general) the standard value for RS is the `\n` char? Having embedded '\n

Comment: Nope - it is data from sql base - after select it goes throught ` sed 's/\t/","/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/;s/\n//g'`

Comment: so the data is originally tab-delimited? Why are you munging it as CSV with quoted strings? Again, the real problem (left incomplete in my comment above) is how can you distinguish between imbedded newlines in a column value VS the newline that terminates a record?  Overall, what your doing doesn't make sense to me. Are you fmting to load into excel or access? You might want to include a sentence or two about what are you ultimate goals in doing this. Good luck.

Comment: how come the embedded new lines are still in your data after `s/\n//g`?